# Duvidas com exercício em Shellscript

Tags: linux, script, bash

Gostaria de alguma ajuda para resolver esses exercícios:

No script ex4.1.sh acrescente a opção para entrar com a palavra e o nome do arquivo diretamente da linha de comando desta forma:

```
$  ./ex4.1.sh  <palavra>  <arquivo>
```

No script ex4.1.sh o resultado do comando “grep” é mostrado na tela. Altere o script de tal forma que não apareça este resultado na tela.
Escreva um script que testa se o valor passado como parâmetro dia, mês e ano é uma data válida.

O script no caso é esse daqui:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ex4.1.sh - teste de desvio
# Script para verificacao de estrutura de desvio
# localiza uma string em um arquivo
echo -n "Digite a palavra a ser localizada: "
read palavra
echo -n "Qual o arquivo a procurar?: "
read arquivo
if grep $palavra $arquivo
 then
   echo "$palavra encontrada no arquivo $arquivo"
   sleep 5
 else
   echo "$palavra não encontrada no arquivo $arquivo"
   sleep 5
 fi
```

Olá colega fedorqui consegui resolver esse exemplo que você deu, o problema é que estava fazendo ele como se fosse um script com o código digitado no gedit quando era pra digitar direto no prompt de comando do linux, ai está o resultado

$ date -d "holaaa" 2> /dev/null && echo "Correto" || echo "Incorreto"

Incorreto

$ date -d "06 Dec 2017" 2> /dev/null && echo "Correto" || echo "Incorreto"

Qua Dez  6 00:00:00 AMT 2017

Correto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No script ex4.1.sh acrescente a opção para entrar com a palavra e o nome do arquivo diretamente da linha de comando desta forma:

Pega os valores com `$1`, `$2`...:

```
palavra=$1
arquivo=$2
```

Assim, `$palavra` contém o primeiro e `$arquivo` o segundo:

Com `script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

palavra=$1
arquivo=$2
echo "palavra: $palavra. arquivo: $arquivo"
```

Vou executar:

```
$ ./script.sh "uma palavra" "hola.txt"
palavra: uma palavra. arquivo: hola.txt
```

---

> Altere o script de tal forma que não apareça este resultado na tela

Pega os resultados en uma variável:

```
res=$(grep "$palavra" "$arquivo")
```

---

> Escreva um script que testa se o valor passado como parâmetro dia, mês e ano é uma data válida.

Usa `date -d"<fecha>"`:

```
$ date -d"holaaa" && echo "correcto" || echo "incorreto"
date: invalid date ‘holaaa’
incorreto
$ date -d"23 Mar 2017" && echo "correcto" || echo "incorreto"
Thu Mar 23 00:00:00 CET 2017
correcto
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Não estou conseguindo fazer o exericio 3, estou recebendo de mensagens de erro de comando não encontrado, fiz o script assim: #!/bin/bash
# ex4.7.sh - teste de data
# Script para verificacao de datas

$ date -d "<holaaa>" && echo "correto" || echo "incorreto"
incorreto
date: invalid date 'holaaa'
$ date -d "<28 Mar 2017>" && echo "correto || echo "incorreto"

correto

Comment: @Fumero o formato é sem `< >` --> `date -d"28 Mar 2017"`. Mas qual é a sua pergunta exatamente?

Comment: Já ajeitei e tirei o sinal de maior e o erro que aparece é esse: ./ex4.7.sh: linha 5: $: comando não encontrado
incorreto
./ex4.7.sh: linha 6: incorreto: comando não encontrado
./ex4.7.sh: linha 7: date:: comando não encontrado
./ex4.7.sh: linha 8: $: comando não encontrado
incorreto
./ex4.7.sh: linha 9: Thu: comando não encontrado
./ex4.7.sh: linha 10: correto: comando não encontrado

Comment: Está bem. Observe minha resposta deu idéias amplas sobre como resolver isso, você tem que colocar esforço sozinho no script. Além disso, melhor atualizar sua pergunta com este código e perguntas específicas sobre o que está falhando. Obrigado!